# How to show primeNg sideBar only inside the child div element?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

**Here is my code**

```
 <div style="  background-color: yellow; height: 350px; padding-top: 45%;">
  <p-button
    type="button"
    (click)="visibleSidebar1 = true"
    icon="pi pi-arrow-right">
  </p-button>

  <div style="background-color: green; height: 250px;">

    <p-sidebar [(visible)]="visibleSidebar1" [baseZIndex]="10000">
      <h1 style="font-weight:normal">Left Sidebar</h1>
    </p-sidebar>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I have use sideBar inside the child element But it is showing in outside the child element. like this [sidebar in outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0arj.jpg)

But i want to show the side bar inside the child element (green area). like this [this is what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToKMe.jpg)

Have any way to achieve this? [my stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-sidebar-demo-xdzabu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please define below CSS properties in your "`**\src\styles.css**" file

```
p-sidebar div.p-sidebar 
{    
    position: relative !important;
}
```